# How to copy multiple records in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, field, record

I have a table "tb_products" in the MySql database with a field "ID" as primary key and auto increment; what's the best practice in SQL to select multiple records by ID and copy them in the same table with new incremented IDs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tb_products
SELECT NULL id, field1, field2, field3, ...
FROM tb_products
WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3, ...)
```

The field list in the `SELECT` clause should be all fields except `id`.

Comment: The fields in the `SELECT` need to match the number of fields in the table you are inserting into.  If you don't want to copy the `id`, then you need to `SELECT NULL`, or add a field list in the `INSERT` (`INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,...)`).

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO NewTbl(Field_1,Field_2,...)
SELECT Field_1,Field_2,...
FROM OldTbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql's insert select http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html, and when your selecting from the existing table, you simply omit selecting the ID, and allow the new table to generate the new id's